# External HDMI Touch screen control for Android

Tags: touchscreen, hdmi, external-display, mhl

I would like to have an external touchscreen for my smartphone (galaxy S8) in order to control it through this screen in my car.
Is the mhl protocol, with basic touchscreen (like capacitive 7 inch) works or do i need to do something different ?
Thx !

Comment: I thought HDMI was about audio and video only?

Comment: No, for exemple i can use it for Rpi or for the ODroid XU4 through hdmi.

Comment: Can you link to the RPi example. All I've found is that a [touchscreen connects to the DSI port on the RPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/the-eagerly-awaited-raspberry-pi-display/) which Android devices DO NOT have.

Comment: Ah, you're right...it needs usb too. So how can i do it like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sikJ_GhwxPw ? So displaying is ok but now i need to send command for the touch control...